# Value does not fall within the expected range, when adding parameters, oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

When adding parameters to Oracle Stored Procedure in Unit Testing, i get error on adding RowId. I tried adding ToString() but then another error - "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CultureInsert'". I am not sure i am getting to the procedure. The error is in the DoInsert function.

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertTest()
{
    var culture = new Culture();
    var insertData = new CultureData();
    insertData.Name = "insertedName5";
    insertData.Code = "en-HK";
    insertData.Description = "InsertDescription";

    var data = culture.Insert(insertData);
}

________________________________________________________

public CultureData Insert(CultureData data)
{
    try
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" + "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))" + "(CONNECT_DATA =" + "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" + "(SERVICE_NAME = XE)));" + "User Id= ****;Password=****;";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmm = new OracleCommand("CultureInsert",conn))
        {

            cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (data.Name != null && data.Code != null && data.Description != null)
            {
                DoInsert(cmm, data);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.Exception(string.Format("Inserting record failed! Name, Code and Description must be entered!"));
            }

        }
        conn.Dispose();

    }
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        SqlExceptionHandler.Throw(exception);
    }

    return data;
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE           CultureInsert(
  v_Id              IN OUT NUMBER,
    v_Code            IN NVARCHAR2,
    v_Name            IN NVARCHAR2,
    v_Description     IN NVARCHAR2,
    v_Disabled        IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    v_RowId           IN RAW,
    v_AuditUser       IN NVARCHAR2,
    v_AuditSessionId  IN RAW)
   as
   v_TransactionName  CHAR(32);
   v_TransCount  NUMBER(10,0);
   v_DisplayField  NVARCHAR2(24);
   SWV_TRANCOUNT NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN

   v_TransactionName := 'CultureInsert';

   v_TransCount := 1  /*NOT SUPPORTED @@TRANCOUNT*/;

   IF (v_TransCount = 0) then
      SAVEPOINT v_TransactionName;
      SWV_TRANCOUNT := 0;
      SWV_TRANCOUNT := SWV_TRANCOUNT+1;
   ELSE
      NULL;
      -- SAVE TRANSACTION @TransactionName
end if;

   BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Core.Culture(Code,
            Name,
            Description,
            Disabled,
            RowId_)
        VALUES(v_Code,
            v_Name,
            v_Description,
            v_Disabled,
            v_RowId);

      select Core.Culture_Id.CURRVAL into v_Id from dual;
      Core.CultureAuditInsert(v_Id,v_AuditUser,'I',v_AuditSessionId);
      Core.CultureFetch(v_Id,v_AuditUser,v_AuditSessionId);
      v_DisplayField := Core.GetCultureDisplayFieldById(v_Id);
      Core.RecentWorkSave('Core','Culture',v_Id,v_DisplayField,v_AuditUser);
      IF v_TransCount = 0 then
         COMMIT;
         SWV_TRANCOUNT := SWV_TRANCOUNT -1;
      end if;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
         IF SWV_TRANCOUNT > 0 then
            ROLLBACK;
            SWV_TRANCOUNT := 0;
         end if;
         --THROW;
   END;

END;
```

here is where i get an error:

```
internal static CultureData DoInsert(OracleCommand cmm, CultureData data)
{
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.IdProperty, data.Id);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.CodeProperty, data.Code);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.NameProperty, data.Name);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.DescriptionProperty, data.Description);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.DisabledProperty, data.Disabled);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.RowIdProperty, data.RowId); //here is the problem
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.AuditUserProperty, Csla.ApplicationContext.User.Identity.Name);
    cmm.Parameters.Add(CultureData.AuditSessionIdProperty, Csla.ApplicationContext.User.Identity.GetSessionId());
    using (OracleDataReader reader = cmm.ExecuteReader())
        return DoFetch(DataReaderHelper.GetReader(reader));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ROWID` pseudocolumn is automatically generated. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm):

> You cannot insert, update, or delete a value of the ROWID pseudocolumn.

Comment: If i delete that line i get this error:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CULTUREINSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Comment: I might not be getting to the procedure, since it is in Other Users - >Core. How can i access procedures in Other Users?

Comment: I resolved it. The procedure was invalid. The insert into statement was faulty and also for disabled it needs 0(zero) or 1(one) for true and false.